# Why does C support _Complex?

Tags: c, keyword, c99

Complex numbers don't seem to me that widely used. But still C99 introduces not one, but two keywords about them (`_Complex` and `_Imaginary`). To me it seems that those belong in a library, and possibly not even the standard library.

*Why are complex numbers so important to the standardization committee of  the C language?* More important than pixels, 3D points, files, time.

Comment: The Rationale for C99 says: "Complex types were added to C as part of the effort to make C suitable and attractive for general numerical programming. Complex arithmetic is used heavily in certain important application areas. The underlying implementation of the complex types is Cartesian, rather than polar, for overall efficiency and consistency with other programming languages. The implementation is explicitly stated so that characteristics and behaviors can be defined simply and unambiguously." Your work doesn't make heavy use of complex numbers; neither does mine. Other people's work does.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yes, I do appreciate the rationale as an answer (as I don't know how to find it). Still, to argue - C is a general-purpose language. Multithreading and memory alignment (the other concepts new to c99) make sense to everyone. Complex numbers - only to scientists and GPU programmers. Equally useful would be to have `_Pixel` keyword, no?

Comment: Multithreading was added to C11, not C99.  Ditto memory alignment.  You seem to have a somewhat blinkered view — those features make sense to you, but not to everyone; complex numbers make sense to some people, but not to you. I can't think what I'd do with `_Pixel` apart from cry "what on earth were they thinking" — the standard does not attempt to cover graphics — but I know I could use complex. Accept that you do not know everything about application areas for C (I know I don't).  You can find the rationale on the C Standard Committee's [web site](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - I think the OP is asking "are complex numbers really more widely-used than graphics concepts?".

Comment: Is it useful to try to standardise complex numbers? Yes. Is it useful to try to standardise graphics concepts? I doubt it.

Comment: A lot of C99 changes were designed to encourage old Fortran programs to come over to C